# Modifying values in a column using for loops

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to modify values in a column of a dataframe. I want values in this column smaller than 0 to be multiplied by 0.1368 and values greater than 0 to be multiplied by 0.179

```r
for(i in all_FR$energy){
  if(i < 0){
    i*0.1368
  } else{
    i*0.179
  }
}
```

I've tried this but it doesn't change the values in the column... any pointers to make this work?

Comment: You can try this `all_FR$energy_new <- with(all_FR, ifelse(energy<0, energy*0.1368, energy*0.179))`.

Comment: You have to assign the result of your calculation.

Comment: @Ethan - it's rarely necessary or desirable to use subscripting and loops for this type of thing